# Add an artificial "label" in the Gmail label list?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search, inbox-by-gmail

Because I extensively use the new *Inbox by Gmail*, and it's feature to bundle certain emails in my inbox once a day/week, but I also still use the standard *Gmail*, I like to see what's *really* in my useable inbox (that's not in one of these bundles) by this search:

> has:nouserlabels  in:inbox

Is there any way to get a link to this simple search as an option in my label list on the left, or even to replace the *Inbox* option with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Enable the **Quick links** Lab, and add to it the URL of your Gmail search.

To add the "Quick links" lab, do the following

1. Go to Settings (cog wheel) > Settings
2. Click on the Labs tab
3. Search for Quick links
4. Click the related Enable radio button
5. Click on the Save changes button.

Once the Quick links is enabled it will be available in the left panel. If you have Chat or Hangouts enable, you should click the ... button to display the side panel gadgets.

The Quick Links has ha button +/- to expand/collapse it.
To add a link,

1. If the Quick links gadget is collapsed, click the + button to expand it
2. Click the "Add quick link" link.
3. A popup will be displayed. Add the URL to your Gmail search
4. Click the OK button.